# How do I remove special characters from file name with a command?

Tags: command-line, scripts, rename, batch-rename

I have a few files that I want to rename and want to accomplish this in the command line.

I need to remove these characters "¡¿" from the beginning of the file names.

From this:

```
¡Tú_la_llevas!-2018.mp4
¿quien_como_tu?.mp4
```

To be like this:

```
Tú_la_llevas!-2018.mp4
quien_como_tu?.mp4
```

Comment: You can use rename `rename -n -E 's/(¿|¡)//' *.mp4`. `-n` just prints the result without actually do anything (remove it when You are ready to rename files). Just put more characters to remove inside the brackets `()` and join them with pipe `|`. Also see `man rename` for more info about the command.

Comment: If the files are inside /opt/server/files how will this command be applied? - it will be run on a cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to install `rename`:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Then, `cd` to the directory containing the files and test by running the following command:

```
rename -n 's/^(¡|¿)(.+)\.mp4$/$2.mp4/' *
```

If you are satisfied with the output, rename the files by running the following command:

```
rename 's/^(¡|¿)(.+)\.mp4$/$2.mp4/' *
```

---

[@graveangel](https://askubuntu.com/users/983716/graveangel):

To run this as a cronjob on all the files in `/opt/server/` directory, pleas follow these steps to make it into a shell script that you can then run as a cronjob:

**Firstly**, create a file with the name  `myrename.sh` for example. You can crate it anywhere you want.

**Secondly**, copy and paste the following into the file and save it:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /opt/server

rename 's/^(¡|¿)(.+)\.mp4$/$2.mp4/' *
```

**Thirdly**, make the file executable:

```
chmod +x myrename.sh
```

**Finally**, test it and use it with `bash /FULL_PATH/myrename.sh`.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this command will be run as a cron job and the files are located within /opt/server/files... how can the command be applied then?

Comment: @graveangel No problem, it will run fine. cronjobs run as root. If for any reason `rename` did not work, try adding the full path to it and use it instead of `rename`. Run `which rename` in the terminal to get the full path, the output would be something like `/usr/bin/rename`

Comment: Meant to say the files I want to rename are inside /opt/server/files

Comment: @graveangel I will update the answer with that. One moment please

Comment: @Raffa cronjobs do not run as root by default. To make root cronjob use: sudo crontab -u root -e

Comment: @inemanja Are you being sophisticated? :)  `sudo crontab -e` will do the job it will run like root. I did not really mean the ROOT. :)