Renaming a LARGE numer of FOLDERS
I have been asked to take over a company site due to the..shall we say unusal and confusing things the last admin was doing...on several of the servers folders were named in the following way..thinking it would be eaiser for the different departments to use
Examples:
!!!-$$ TEST-1 $$-!!!  
!!!-$$ TEST-2 $$-!!!
##-$ TEST-2 $-##      
##-$ TEST-3 $-##
&-$ TEST3 $-&         
&-$ TEST4 $-&

Now I could go on but I believe you get the idea...so my question is this

How do I RENAME MULTUPLE FOLDERS and REMOVE THE all of the SYMBOLS but keep the folder names??


this one is also good: https://askubuntu.com/a/1178992/15811 just replace the chars changed there with the ! and the $ and the & It also have a tester so you can check upfront

Determine a list of directory names you want to rename.
Defines a function that removes all non-alphanumeric characters, leaving only letters, numbers, and hyphens.
Iterates over the list of directories, applies the function to each one, and then uses the mv command to rename the directory if it exists.
